# Bind variable "Select" is not declared error?

Tags: sql, plsql

I get this error when I want to run my anonymous block

```
Bind Variable "select" is NOT DECLARED
anonymous block completed
```

What's the cause of this error? and how do I stop it? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to select sysdate from dual, and a few other issues.

```
declare
  filename varchar2(21) := to_char(sysdate, '"MED_LIST_"DD_MM_YY".csv"');
Begin 
  execute immediate 'alter table ext_table location ('''||filename||''')';
end;
```